# How can I remove this arrow panel from my code view in Dreamweaver CS6?

Tags: dreamweaver

[image: Arrow panel in code view]

It appeared at some point of me writing code and I don't know how to remove this panel so that it doesn't get in the way of my code.

*Update: Though it has since gone away, I don't how, I still think this is worth knowing should it come back / other users experience this.

Comment: Hi @WarrenvanRooyen when posting on webmasters it's ideal that you try and provide as much details as possible so we can help. What version of dreamweaver are you using?

Comment: Sorry I've updated the headline detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like a inactive scroll bar that got drawn in the wrong place.  I'd wager it is a bug in dreamweaver.  Try closing the program and re-opening it.

If it persists, it could be related to the "code view" settings.  You might want to toggle settings like "word wrap" as explained at [Adobe Dreamweaver CS5 on Demand: Viewing the HTML Behind the Page](http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1588847&seqNum=6)